# How to load data with a self look up field?

Tags: lookup, data, data-import-wizard, data-import

I have a table with has a self loop up field. i.e. Table is called foo__c with a field Previous__c that is a lookup to foo__c

Currently, I am trying to load a CSV with two rows. 
The first row is foo__c without any value for Previous__c,
The second row is foo__c with the "name__c" field of the first row in the Previous__c column.

With this import I get the 2nd row failing to import due to "cannot find row with the name loopup in the CSV". This makes me think that while importing the first row cannot be referenced by the 2nd row during the import... ?

Is it possible to load everything for a row including the self look up field using data import wizard?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem here is, when you try to access the `name__c` on the second row, the name has to be retrieved from the parent record of the record you inserted in the first row. To access the `name__c` in the second row, I believe you have to insert the parent record before accessing any fields from that record.